# How can I determine the number of vCPUs from the command line on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to determine the number of vCPUs on an EC2 instance when my app starts up, so that I can set an appropriate number of threads.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

`nproc` will return the number of cores, which is equivalent to the number of vCPUs. This is a good number of threads to use.